# alignParentBottom with toggling visibility

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a layout like this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="parent">
        <LinearLayout id="child1"
                      layout_above="+id/child2"/>
        <LinearLayout id="child2"
                      gravity="bottom"
                      alignParentBottom="true"
                      visibility="gone"/>
    <FloatingActionButton/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

The layout `child2` (which is GONE by default) has an `EditText` and a `Button` in it, aligned vertically. Upon certain action, I want `child2` to be on top of the keyboard when the focus is on the `EditText`. When that action happens, I toggle the visibility of `child2` to VISIBLE but the issue is that only the `EditText` is visible when the keyboard is up and not the `Button` below it.

When I take out `visibility=GONE` from the layout, it works fine. The whole `child2` is anchored to the keyboard as expected but when I make it `GONE` by default and make it visible on my action, only the `EditText` is visible above the keyboard and the whole view is not anchored to the keyboard. I also tried `adjustResize` in the `Activity` but that didn't work as well. Any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my activity was setting the `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` because of which it ignored the value of windowSoftInputMode as stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_FULLSCREEN):

> Window flag: hide all screen decorations (such as the status bar)
>   while this window is displayed. This allows the window to use the
>   entire display space for itself -- the status bar will be hidden when
>   an app window with this flag set is on the top layer. A fullscreen
>   window will ignore a value of SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE for the
>   window's softInputMode field; the window will stay fullscreen and will
>   not resize.

A rather embarrassing moment! (facepalm)